# HTML page with multiple selection text changing according to previous choices

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to write an HTML code similar to the one below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="text">This is some text with a few <select id="mySelect1">
  <option value="word1">Word 1</option>
  <option value="word2">Word 2</option>
</select> that can be changed and a <select id="mySelect2">
  <option value="word3">Word 3</option>
  <option value="word4">Word 4</option>
</select> that can be replaced too</p>

<button onclick="displayText()">Display Text</button>

<script>
function displayText() {
  var select1 = document.getElementById("mySelect1");
  var selectedOption1 = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
  
  var select2 = document.getElementById("mySelect2");
  var selectedOption2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
  
  var text = "This is some text with a few " + selectedOption1 + " that can be changed and a " + selectedOption2 + " that can be replaced too";
  var newPage = window.open();
  newPage.document.write(text);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But the text and option will change based on choices made in previous selection boxes.
E.g. if I choose in the first selection box option 2 then the following sentences and choices will be changed accordingly.
It should be some kind of flow-chart in the background to "program" the form behavior.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Comment: @Ron The MRE requirement is for debugging questions only, not for how-to questions. If people were capable of creating MREs for 'how-to' questions, they wouldn't need to ask in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Styling

### Via CSS

A **CSS-only solution** should exist by using the [relative selector `:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and [combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators). This would remove the need for *any* JS for styling.

Personally, I suggest to use CSS for styling where possible.

Example of using `:has()`:

```css
#p1:has([value="no"]:checked) + #p2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">
  Show <code>#p2</code>?
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="p2">
  This is <code>#p2</code>.
</p>
<p id="p3">
  This is <code>#p3</code>, usually following <code>#p2</code>.
</p>
```

### Via JavaScript

By using *event delegation* (see below) we can write **an `input` listener to update styles**, so that the visible content reflects the content of the new page. Example:

```js
const commonAncestor = document.body;

commonAncestor.addEventListener("input", () => {
  p2.toggleAttribute("hidden", select1.value !== "Yes");
});
```

```html
<p id="p1">
  Activate <code>#p2</code>?
  <select id="select1">
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="p2">
  This is <code>#p2</code>.
</p>
<p id="p3">
  This is <code>#p3</code>, usually after <code>#p2</code>.
</p>
```

You may want to **update the styles initially**, which has to be done after the (relevant) DOM content has loaded:

```js
const commonAncestor = document.body;
commonAncestor.addEventListener("input", updateStyles);

// Using "DOMContentLoaded" should always work:
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateStyles);

function updateStyles() {
  p2.toggleAttribute("hidden", select1.value !== "Yes");
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">
  Activate <code>#p2</code>?
  <select id="select1">
    <!--Notice <select>'s initial value:-->
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option selected>No</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="p2">
  This is <code>#p2</code>.
</p>
<p id="p3">
  This is <code>#p3</code>, usually after <code>#p2</code>.
</p>
```

#### Event delegation

We can handle the [`input` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) of all `<select>`s in a single listener via [**event delegation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation):

```js
const commonAncestor = document.body;

commonAncestor.addEventListener("input", evt => {
  // Handle input events; example: (Log event details)
  const message = `Target ${evt.target.id} changed to value: ${evt.target.value}`;
  console.log(message);
});
```

```html
<select id="select1">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

#### Excursus: Named objects

Elements with IDs are *named objects*. The DOM API provides a way to [**access *named objects* as globals**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object):

```js
console.log(div1);
console.log(div2); // Doesn't exist
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

But **notice this note** in the specification:

> As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code.
> Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time,
> as new features are added to the web platform, for example.
> Instead of this, use `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()`.

So to have non-brittle code, you should *not* rely on named objects to be accessible like this. Instead, you can query for them one by one, and assign each to a variable.

*For brevity of my code snippets only*, I chose to dismiss this warning and use named objects.

Alternatively, instead on relying on this functionality to exist on [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window), you can mock this functionality on any other object with [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
const elements = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return document.getElementById(prop);
  }
});

console.log('As "named objects":');
console.log("-Text of p1:", elements.p1.textContent);
console.log("-Text of p2:", elements.p2.textContent);
console.log("-Text of p3:", elements.p3?.textContent);
```

```html
<p id="p1">First paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">Second paragraph.</p>
```

Or define a helper function, if the only benefit you are after is short code:

```js
function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

console.log('As "named objects":');
console.log("-Text of p1:", byId("p1").textContent);
console.log("-Text of p2:", byId("p2").textContent);
console.log("-Text of p3:", byId("p3")?.textContent);
```

```html
<p id="p1">First paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">Second paragraph.</p>
```

## Get final text

To **get the final text** we can use [`Element.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText), which is styling-aware. That means you only get the visible content; the content we want:

```js
const commonAncestor = document.getElementById("common-ancestor");
commonAncestor.addEventListener("input", updateStyles);
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateStyles);

function updateStyles() {
  p2.toggleAttribute("hidden", select1.value !== "Yes");
}

const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Clone text container
  const clone = commonAncestor.cloneNode(true);
  
  // Replace <select>s with their selected option
  const selectElements = clone.querySelectorAll("select");
  selectElements.forEach(clonedSelect => {
    const select = document.getElementById(clonedSelect.id);
    
    // Use either as replacement
    const selectedValue = select.value;
    const selectedLabel = select.selectedOptions[0].textContent;
    
    clonedSelect.replaceWith(selectedValue);
  });
  
  // Get style-aware content
  document.body.append(clone);
  const text = clone.innerText;
  clone.remove();
  
  // Use content
  console.log("Text:", text);
});
```

```html
<div id="common-ancestor">
  <p id="p1">
    Show <code>#p2</code>?
    <select id="select1">
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option selected>No</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p id="p2">
    This is <code>#p2</code>.
  </p>
  <p id="p3">
    This is <code>#p3</code>, usually after <code>#p2</code>.
  </p>
</div>

<button type="button">Log text</button>
```

**Sidenote**: When styling via CSS, you would have to stringify the paragraphs and replace the `<select>`s in *reverse tree-order*, because you specified that no elements prior to but only following a `<select>` are affected.

When styling via JS (as in the example above), you shouldn't have any problems, since the elements have their styles inlined.

### Explanation

Unfortunately, a stringified `<select>` includes all its options, so we have to replace the `<select>` with its selected option manually (e.g. with [`Element.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)).

To not destroy our DOM, we can work on a [cloned subtree via `Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

Cloning a node clones its "HTML representation", which for `<select>`s doesn't include the user-selection. Since the cloned and original `<select>` should select the same option, we can get the expected selected option by the original's [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) (or similar). We can get the corresponding original `<select>` via its ID, since the clone has the same.

The content getter `Element.innerText` is only style-aware if the element is part of a DOM tree. This means we have to briefly append it to the DOM to work correctly.